# Trying to post object with parameters - angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-get

I am trying to do a http get in angular like this:

```
$http
    .get(some url, {
        params: {
            description: params.description,
            from: params.from,
            to: params.to
        }
     })
     .success(function (data,status) {
          $scope.info_show = data
     });
```

here's the thing, the `params` object parameters are set based in user input, so if the user hasn't inputted anything for the from property (some input text fielt) it will be undefined.

my problem is that I can't just pass the params object, because it doesn't filter and if I pass undefined on even one of the properties then the web service by default will return everything, could someone show me a way of dynamically doing this?

Comment: can you provide html for your form as well, it'll be easier to find a solution for you

Comment: You are using params as the object name and as the input.

Comment: @topless it is going to give me the same result if I change it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function to filter the `params` object.

This one receives a list of params/properties you want to filter and the `src` object to filter from:

```
var filterParams = function(params, src) {
  var result = {};
  angular.forEach(params, function(p) {
    if (angular.isDefined(src[p])) {
      result[p] = src[p];
    }
  });
  return result;
};
```

And then use it like this:

```
$http.get(some url, {
    params: filterParams(['from', 'to', 'description'], params)
})
.success(function (data,status) {
    $scope.info_show = data
});
```